# $\mathcal{D}(0,T;V)$ is dense in $W(0,T)$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes

Where can I find a proof that $\mathcal{D}(0,T;V)$ (the space of $V$-valued compactly supported functions on $[0,T]$) is dense in the space $W(0,T)$, where $$W(0,T) := \{ u \in L^2(0,T;V) : u' \in L^2(0,T;V^*)\},$$ where $V$ is Hilbert\Banach? I need the proof in the English language.

Comment: What is $T$? What do the $0$s mean? What is $\mathcal{D}$? Is this question research-level?

Comment: $[0,T]$ is an interval. This is a research-level question.

Comment: A standard reference on this is the monograph by Lions and Magenes: Non-Homogeneous Boundary Value Problems and Applications. Everyone refers to it for the proof...

Comment: Volume 1: http://rd.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-65161-8/page/1 , but there are three.

Comment: @AndrasBatkai thank you a lot. Unfortunately I don't have access to that. Do you have a PDF of that (if legal, otherwise obviously ignore this)?