# $C_c^{\infty}([0,T];V)$ is dense in $C_c^{1}([0,T];V)$?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, fa.functional-analysis

Is it true that the space $C_c^{\infty}([0,T];V)$ is dense in $C_c^{1}([0,T];V)$? These are compactly supported functions that are $V$ valued, where $V$ is a Banach or Hilbert space.

Comment: Convolution with a smooth compactly supported bump function?

Comment: Isn't it superfluous to require compact support, given that the domain is a compact interval?

Comment: @MTS: $C_c^\infty(K) = \lbrace f\in C^\infty(\mathbb R): \mathrm{supp}(f) \subseteq K\rbrace$.

Comment: A related question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/130276/mathcald0-tv-is-dense-in-w0-t


Answer (score 2):

As Andre suggests: Convolution with smooth bump function with very small support
will give you an approximation by a smooth function which however need not have support in $[0,T]$. However, you may first squeeze the support of the given function you want
to approximate in order to make its support a compact subset of $(0,T)$. Then the support
of the convolution stays in $[0,T]$ if the support of the bump function is small enough.